# Postfix send email but not receive it. NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from ; Relay access denied

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server

Postfix was configured and it can send emails using gmail domain relay.
However Postfix can't receive emails from external domains.

My internal email is: commercial@mail.something.com

Versions:
Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark) ; Postfix 3.2.3

**Below my setups;**

- The ports 25 and 587 are open in GCP where postfix was configured
- There is an user commercial name created in Linux where postfix was configured
- MX and A DNS were setup and below you can see report yielded from dig linux command:

**Below my extra setups;**

```
something.com.         59      IN      MX      10 mail.something.com.
mail.something.com.    59      IN      A       <SOMETHING IP ADDRESS>
```

**$ sudo postconf -n**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname mail.$myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost
myhostname = something.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

**$ sudo postconf -M**

```
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

I spent a lot of hours trying to solve it but until now I couldn't because probably it's not my main skill. I'm getting better...

**Could you please** check it and guide me to turn on the postfix to receive email? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mydestination` doesn't have `mail.example.com`, just the plain `example.com`.

```
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost
myhostname = example.com
```

You could add it e.g. like this:

```
mydestination = $myhostname mail.$myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost
```

However, you probably want to receive mail for `user@example.com`, not `mail.example.com`? For this you'd need to set `MX` for it, instead:

```
example.com.         IN      MX      10 mail.example.com.
mail.example.com.    IN      A       198.51.100.100
```

Comment: I did what you told me. Postfix sends email, but to receive the message: "NOQUEUE: reject" "Relay access denied" still continue showing on the log file. I mean, postfix doesn't receive email from external domains.

Comment: checking deeply the configuration I solve it. Thanks to Esa Jokinen for your insights. The setups are updated to help some friend on it.

Comment: Due to the Q/A nature it'd be better if you keep the errors on your question and answer with the necessary modifications.

Comment: @EsaJokinen, DNS setting should use `@` instead of `domain.com`.For example,`@        IN      MX      10 mail.example.com.`

Comment: @kittygirl: The `@` is substituted with zone apex in the BIND zones. Therefore, `@` equals `example.com.` and both can be used, but `@` alone in examples doesn't mean anything specific. See http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/apa/origin.html

Comment: @EsaJokinen,with your DNS setting, only change `myhostname = example.com` to `myhostname = mail.example.com`.is that ok?

Comment: That would require additional `example.com` in `mydestination`.